# Blue accessibility frame around elements in Slack after using JAWS screen reared

Tags: electron, windows-10, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I had a screen reader JAWS installed for some time, then I properly uninstalled it from the All Apps setting in Windows.

After that when Grammarly (text corrector) is launched, there's a blue box around UI elements in Slack. If I close Grammarly, then the blue box disappears. This happens only in Slack.

[image]

I contacted Slack support, and they said since Slack is built on electron, it uses the API provided by electron, and the external app was setting '[app.setAccessibilitySupportEnabled(enabled)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/accessibility#using-electrons-api)' attribute in electron API, that's why the blue box appears. Apparently, it was Grammarly, because if I close it, Slack works well without the blue box.

What I tried:

1. in the Control panel -> Ease of access center unchecked everything
2. In All Settings -> Narrator unchecked everything
3. in Chrome, went to chrome://accessibility and unchecked everything, but if I had Grammarly launched it checked all the checkboxes back
4. as mentioned [here](https://github.com/widget-/slack-black-theme/pull/53/files), I run a dev console from within Slack and tried to run app.setAccessibilitySupportEnabled(disabled), but it gave me an 'Uncaught Reference Error: app is not defined' error

Any ideas on how I can change app.setAccessibilitySupportEnabled back to disabled?

Comment: You probably used JAWS, right? Maybe install it and then uninstall it. No guarantees, but that might fix it. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/accessibility#using-electrons-api

Comment: In Chrome, try visiting chrome://accessibility and unchecking any checked checkboxes.

Comment: @Gantendo you're right, it was JAWS. Tried to install and uninstall it, but that didn't help. If JAWS changes something in the system where Grammarly is taking the properties from, maybe there's a way to change this property back to the initial value?

Comment: Thanks @Gantendo! I tried to post there but there's a 90 mins delay preventing me from posting

Comment: By the way, chrome://accessibility/ didn't help. I disabled everything and relaunched Slack, but nothing changed

Comment: Yeah you have to do something I barely remember reading about ages ago. I think you have to do something like solution 1 here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/955dro/how_do_i_open_the_chromium_developer_tools_in_the/ and then in the Console type app.setAccessibilitySupportEnabled(disabled) but I am 0.0001% sure. Someone will tell us.

Comment: @Gantendo did it, so now I have a dev console opened for Slack (I see the markup from Slack), but when I run the command in console there I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from the Grammarly team, and it helped:

1. Install JAWS again
2. Choose "Options" => "Restore to Factory Settings"
3. Uninstall JAWS

Initially, I was deleting JAWS from Windows 10 apps list.
It had two programs related to JAWS, so I uninstalled both of them.

This time I also went to Control Panel -> Programs and Features.
There I filtered the list by the developer name, and there was one of the programs developed by Freedom Scientific (so it was the third one), so I uninstalled it from there. After the reboot, the issue was gone!

I don't know what exactly helped ("Restore to Factory Settings" or the deletion of the third program), but I'm happy now!